# Google Analytics indicates tracking code is not installed

Tags: google-analytics

I have 4 websites using Google Analytics. Two of them are being tracked perfectly without any problem. The other two however are appearing as "Tracking Not Installed". It's there, but it's not working for these sites:

```
www.evusa.org
www.usagreencard.co.uk
```

It really makes me feel not very confident about using Google Analytics now. If the tracking code appears as "not installed" when it is actually installed, why I should feel sure that the numbers they provide are actually real.

Here's the tracking code for the first site:

```
<!-- GA -->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-49488235-8', 'usagreencard.co.uk');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

And here's the tracking code for the second site:

```
<!-- GA -->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-49488235-7', 'evusa.org');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Chris- Welcome to Pro Webmasters! I saw that message once and it seemed to resolve itself somehow. I wish I had an answer! Someone will. I do not put too much faith in Google Analytics since bots are clearly tracked and skew Bounce Rates, Time on Site, Time on Page, and so on. Still, all and all, it is an excellent part of anyone's arsenal. The reason is simple- Google has vital data that no-one else has. Just take the user tracking data with some salt.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome @closetnoc. Considering there's no phone number to call them, and how much they care about these things. I'm moving to Piwik.

Comment: Excellent choice! GA is good to help guide your SEO efforts. I look at it almost every day. I also use external tools such as SEO and user analysis. It augments what I do well.

Answer (score 2):

Your tracking code is not within the `<head> </head>` section of either sites source code. This is where [Google stipulates](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) that should add the code, so this could be the reason why it is not tracking.

You can check this yourself by simply viewing your pages source code and searching for the code, you will see it in the body.

You can also the [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) Chrome extension to  troubleshoot installation of various Google tags.

However, having said I've seen GA accounts tracking fine even with the code outside of the `<head>` before; so I would move the tag to the correct position, then report back your findings if its still not tracking.

Comment: The fact that the tracking code is not in the `<head>` of the page will not cause the `Tracking Not Installed` flag (unless there are parts of the page inaccessible to crawlers) which you did touch upon in your last sentence.

Comment: However, it's seems pretty logical it should be the first thing to correct, no?

Comment: No. Not really. It is a recommendation, nothing more. In some instances, websites would not want tracking code on every page of their website. Google will see the tracking code wherever it is placed within the page providing it can be accessed by a crawler.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's not that, it's on the head because I moved 300 times, trying to make it read it.

Comment: Chris, it's still not in the head section, its just outside the closing </head>. You can view the source code and see where it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth checking under Admin -> Property Settings in GA that the default URL is actually the same as the URL of the domain the tracking code is installed on.

I know in the past I've put a placeholder URL in here before launching a site, forgot to change it on launch, and then GA reports no tracking code installed, because there isn't one at the URL you're telling it to look at!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have perfectly copied the code as place in the required areas.See if you are using WordPress use a plugin like Google analytics and directory you can authenticate with that and for blogger you can directly place tracking code like UA-xxxxxxx
in Blogger `dashboard>settings>other>google analytics`.

And please note it takes nearly **24hrs** to get installed.